# Is it possible to intentionally draw a game?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was told today that it's possible to do an effective "friendly mulligan" (draw to 7 cards) by intentionally tying the game and starting a new one.

I've heard of people intentionally drawing matches a lot of times, but is it legal to intentionally draw a single game?

Comment: I'm not sure you can intentionally draw a match directly. You can only intentionally draw your games, which ends up resulting in a drawn match.

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, you can, see my answer "if a game or **match** is not completed". An intentional draw in a match is always reported as 0-0-3, even if both players each won a game before they decided to draw the match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.

From the tournamet rules:

> 2.4  Conceding or Intentionally Drawing Games or Matches
>
> If a game or match is not completed, players may concede or mutually agree to a
>   draw in that game or match. A  match is considered complete once the
>   result slip is filled out or, if match slips are not being used, a
>   player leaves  the table after game play is finished. Until that
>   point, either player may concede to or draw with the other, though  if
>   the conceding player won a game in the match, the match must be
>   reported as 2-1. Intentional draws are always  reported as 0-0-3.
>
> Players may not agree to a concession or draw in exchange for any
>   reward or incentive. Doing so will be  considered Bribery (see section
>   5.2).
>
> If a player refuses to play, it is assumed that he or she has conceded the match.

But remember that you can't use the sideboard if you decide to draw before starting to play:

> 2.3  Pregame Procedures
>
> The following steps must be performed in a timely manner before each game begins:
>
> 1. Players may exchange cards in their decks for cards in their sideboards. Players may only do this after  the first or subsequent
>      game of the match and not for games that are restarted or games that
>      are drawn  before any game actions are taken.

Matches are played until time has run out or until a player has won a certain number of games. Therefore drawing a game will not use up one of the games in the match, because there is no limit to the number of games that can be played in a match:

> 2.1  Match Structure
>
> A Magic match consists of a series of games that are played until one side has won a set number of games,  usually two.
>   Drawn games do not count toward this goal. If the round ends before a
>   player has won the required  number of games, the winner of the match
>   is the player who has won the most games at that point. If both
>   players  have equal game wins, the match is a draw.

Comment: Seems like that would use up one of your games in the match (outside top 8, which would allow you to keep playing after going 1-1-1). Is that correct?

Comment: @Guvante There is no limit to the number of games that can be played in a match. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, and you don't even have to trick it.  See rule 104.4i:

> 104.4i In a tournament, all players in the game may agree to an intentional draw.

You can shake hands and agree to a draw at any time.